# FOSRest per bundle. How to configure?

Tags: json, output, config, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm new to symfony and I just started to build a pilot project for learning purposes. Using symfony 3 and having an app I would like to build with FOSRest a JSON based API and another separate bundler should provide the Backend on user authentication for data manipulation. The problem if I add the following in my

```
app/config_dev.yml

fos_rest:
   param_fetcher_listener: true
   body_listener: true
   format_listener: true
   view:
       view_response_listener: 'force'
       formats:
           xml: true
           json : true
       templating_formats:
           html: true
       force_redirects:
           html: true
       failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
       default_engine: twig
   routing_loader:
       default_format: json
```

I get `No engine is able to work with the template ""`.

How do I manage to have separate response per separate bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't configure a 3rd party bundle differently in 2 of your bundles.
But, you can deal with route patterns in the `format_listener` option:

```
fos_rest:
    # ...
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/json', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/html', priorities: ['html'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: false }
```

Like this, the routes matching with `^/json` will render `JSON` and `/html` will render `HTML`by default.

For more, look at [the listener configuration.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html)